# Curl will not post multiple data to server

Tags: c++, http, post, curl, get

I am writing an application for work that needs to perform HTTP requests to a server, and get a response, in JSON back.

At the moment, my code connects to the server, and gets a response back, which is great. However, I also need to send data to the server, which will process it, and send me the jSON.

My problem is that I am able to send, thanks to POSTFIELDS, only a single "field", and won't get any response if I insert more that one.

The code is the following:

```
// writefunc works, so there is no point adding its code in here
size_t Simulator::writefunc(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, struct string *buffer_in);

void Simulator::move(Player *player)
{
    std::ostringstream ss_url;
    ss_url << API_URL << "functionCalled";
    char const *url = ss_url.str().c_str();

    std::ostringstream ss_postfields;

    // This will not work - And all values do NOT contain any space
    // The server do NOT receive any data (in POST and GET)
    ss_postfields  << "user_name=" << player->getName()
                        << "&user_secret=" << player->secret()
                            << "&app_id=" << player->getApp_id()
                                << "&lat=" << player->getLocation()->getLat()
                                    <<"&lon=" << player->getLocation()->getLon();

    // This will not work either
    // ss_postfields << "user_name=nicolas&app_id=2";

    // This works and will send the data to the server, which will receive and process it.
    // ss_postfields << "user_name=" << player->getName();

    const char *postfields = ss_postfields.str().c_str();

    CURL *curl_handle;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl_handle = curl_easy_init();

    if(curl_handle){
        struct string s;
        init_string(&s);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writefunc);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &s);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postfields);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, strlen(postfields));
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
        CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);

        if(CURLE_OK != res)
        {
            printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(res));
            exit(0);
        }

        printf("%s\n", s.ptr);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);
        curl_global_cleanup();
    }
}
```

I thought I would also give the output of CURLOPT_HEADER and CURLOPT_VERBOSE for when I send only 1 value, or multiple values:

When I Send One value only:

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 8888 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* connected
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8888 (#0)
> POST [api_url]  HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8888
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 22
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* upload completely sent off: 22 out of 22 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sun, 24 Nov 2013 17:25:14 GMT
< Server: Apache
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.20
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< X-Debug-Token: a41727
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: application/json
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
0
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 24 Nov 2013 17:25:14 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.20
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Debug-Token: a41727
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json

[ OUTPUT FROM SERVER HERE ]

* Closing connection #0
```

And when I send multiple values:

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 8888 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* connected
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8888 (#0)
> POST [api_url] HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8888
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* upload completely sent off: 1 out of 1 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sun, 24 Nov 2013 17:30:13 GMT
< Server: Apache
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.20
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< X-Debug-Token: d1947e
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: application/json
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
0
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 24 Nov 2013 17:30:13 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.20
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Debug-Token: d1947e
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json

[ OUTPUT FROM SERVER HERE ]

* Closing connection #0
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you seem to be missing an equals sign!

```
   ss_postfields  << "user_name=" << player->getName()
                    << "&user_secret=" << player->secret()
                        << "&app_id=" << player->getApp_id()
                            << "&lat=" << player->getLocation()->getLat()
                                <<"&lon=" << player->getLocation()->getLon();
```

instead of

```
   ss_postfields  << "user_name=" << player->getName()
                    << "&user_secret" << player->secret()
                        << "&app_id=" << player->getApp_id()
                            << "&lat=" << player->getLocation()->getLat()
                                <<"&lon=" << player->getLocation()->getLon();
```

Comment: The equal sign is in my original code but thank you, I will edit it.

Also, as you can see in the code, I've commented out the line with only two values, which does not work. 

From what CURLOPT_HEADER/VERBOSE gives us, we can see that with a simple value, 22 bytes are sent, and 1byte for multiple values. So I tried to see if I could maybe change the postfields size and put it to 46bytes when sending 2 values, and the server gets some weird data that seems to be the address of a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was in a rush, I rewrote everything using HTTP sockets. But I could not be done with this issue, so I went back to it, and finally found the problem. It seems like cUrl does not really like streams.

I thought I would update this post in the case anyone is having the same issue:

Therefore, something like the following will NOT work:

```
std::ostringstream ss_postfields;

// This will not work - And all values do NOT contain any space
// The server do NOT receive any data (in POST and GET)
ss_postfields  << "user_name=" << player->getName()
                    << "&user_secret=" << player->getSecret();

const char *postfields = ss_postfields.str().c_str();
// ...
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postfields);
CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
```

However, and bizarrely, this will work:

```
std::string str_postfields;
std::string user_name = player->getName();
std::string user_secret = player->getSecret();
std::string str_postfields = "user_name=" +user_name +"&user_secret=" +user_secret;

const char *postfields = str_postfields.c_str();
// ...
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postfields);
CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
```

Comment: One possible reason for string stream based version not working could be that postfields in the code - `const char *postfields = ss_postfields.str().c_str();` - would actually be pointing to memory that is already deleted, because `str()` returns a temporary string object.

Comment: Indeed, I've noticed later on that str() returns a temporary object as you said. So the following was actually working:
string s = ss_postfields.str(); 
const char *postfields = s.c_str();